# WPF Datagrid Grouping , displaying autogenrated columns

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am working on a wpf datagrid which is bound to a collection of following class

```
public class SalesData
{
    public string SalesManName{ get; set; }
    public int salesCount{ get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public datetime salesdate{get;set;}            
    public int avgSales{ get; set; }
}
```

on the click of a button in my UI , I am doing the following operation

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Datagrid.ItemsSource);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SalesCount", ListSortDirection.Descending));

PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("SalesManName");

PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription2 = new PropertyGroupDescription("salesdate");
```

Now if What basically happens is it gives me the following result in the datagrid

```
SalesManName | SalesCount | Area   | SalesDate  
AAA          | 2          | London | 05/06/2017 
AAA          | 1          | London | 05/07/2017 
AAA          | 1          | London | 05/08/2017 
AAA          | 2          | London | 05/09/2017 
BBB          | 2          | London | 05/06/2017 
BBB          | 2          | London | 05/07/2017 
BBB          | 2          | London | 05/09/2017
```

What i would like to have is

```
SalesManName | 05/06/2017  | 05/07/2017  | 05/08/2017  | 05/09/2017 
AAA          | 2           |     1       |     1       |   2
BBB          | 2           |     2       |     0       |   2
```

Comment: 1) Add code where you add group descriptions to the `GroupDescriptions` of the `view`. 2) `.GetDefaultView(Datagrid.ItemsSource)` Are you serious? You need to create collection in your view model, wrap it into `ICollectionView` and bind the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to this collection view.

Comment: `PropertyGroupDescription` is not meant for pivoting your data; if you are using MVVM, you can pivot _by yourself_ your `SalesData` collection in new data structure and bind it to your `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same long time ago. Unfortunately I can't recall the post that helped me. The idea consists of using a `DataTable` as the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid` with the converter that will build the datatable.
**Xaml**

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems, Converter={StaticResource SalesDataConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Where `AllItems` is an `ObservableCollection` of `SalesData`

**Converter**

```
public class SalesDataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        const string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";

        var allSalesData = value as IEnumerable<SalesData>;
        var headers = allSalesData.Select(s => s.SalesDate.ToString(format)).Distinct();

        dataTable.Columns.Add("SalesManName");
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(header, typeof(string)));
        }

        var saleDico = allSalesData.GroupBy(s => s.SalesManName)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                SalesManName = g.Key,
                DateAndCount = g.ToList().GroupBy(i => i.SalesDate.ToString(format))
                .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.ToList().Sum(f => f.SalesCount))
            });

        foreach (var item in saleDico)
        {
            var values = new List<string>() { item.SalesManName };
            int count;
            foreach (var h in headers)
            {
                var val = item.DateAndCount.TryGetValue(h, out count) ? count.ToString() : string.Empty;
                values.Add(val);           
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());
        }
        return dataTable.AsDataView();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @adPartage : Your input was helpful. Accepting this as a possible way of achieving what i need. Thanks a ton !!